# Toggling multiple div classes based on visibility through JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to structure a group of links that will `.fadeIn()` `<div>`s based on which ones are clicked.  I would like to `.fadeOut()` any `<div>`s that don't coincide with the current link that is clicked.  I'm hoping it would also be possible to show all/hide all with a link as well.

For example :

```
<a href="#" id="showall">Show All</a>
<a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Link 3</a>
<a href="#" id="link4">Link 4</a>


<div class="all">
   <div class="part1">SOME TEXT</div>
   <div class="part2">SOME TEXT</div>
   <div class="part3">SOME TEXT</div>
   <div class="part4">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>
```

So clicking link 1 would show part 1, and so on and so on.  Now I can't seem to wrap my head around this, because originally my thought was to have a function for each link clicked that read something like :

```
 $("#link1").click(function() {
   $(".all").fadeOut();  //clear any divs that may be visible now
   $(".part1").fadeIn();  // display div coinciding with link   
 });
```

And then for show all simply have :

```
 $("#showall").click(function() {
   $(this).toggle("slow");
 });
```

But, of course I learned that by changing the visibility of a container, all elements within that container will be rendered invisible as well, regardless of if there are two commands in the function (I think.)

So instead, my thought was to write a function for each link that read

```
 $("#link1").click(function() {
   $(".part2, .part3, .part4").fadeOut();  //clear other divs
   $(".part1").fadeIn();  // display div coinciding with link   
 });
```

But I could have upwards of 25 links, and I already know there must be a more efficient way of doing this.  Is it possible to have a filter, perhaps `.all:visible` to tell which are visible and which are not, and then have those fade out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, clicking link1 should hide all divs but the one with class=part1

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
    $("div[class^=part]").fadeOut();
    $("div.part1").fadeIn();
});
```

And then for show all

```
$("#showall").click(function() {
    $("div[class^=part]").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Chibuzo thanks for the response.  This is by far the simplest method and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
$("a:not(#showall)").on("click", function() {
    var index = $(this).index("a:not(#showall)");

    $("div.all div:visible").fadeOut(function() {
        $("div.all div:eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn();
    });
});

$("#showall").on("click", function () {
    $("div.all div").fadeIn();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Zh3a9/

There's a lot going on here, but basically here's what's going on:

- For all anchors *without* the `showall` id, bind an event handler.

  - In that event handler, [determine the "index"](http://api.jquery.com/index) of the link that was clicked, in the context of all links without the `showall` id.
  - Fade out every `div` under `div.all` that are [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).
  - When the fade out completes, fade in the `div` with an index corresponding to the link we clicked.
- For the anchor with the `showAll` id create an event handler that fades in every `div` under `div.all`

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this to get the number of out the clicked id and then figure out which part to show:

```
$("#myLinks a").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "showall") {
        $(".all div").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        var num = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
        var target = $(".part" + num);
        $(".all div").not(target).fadeOut("slow");
        target.fadeIn("slow");
    }
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/eVKDu/

With this slightly modified HTML:

```
<div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#" id="showall">Show All</a>
    <a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="link3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="link4">Link 4</a>
</div>

<div class="all">
   <div class="part1">SOME TEXT1</div>
   <div class="part2">SOME TEXT2</div>
   <div class="part3">SOME TEXT3</div>
   <div class="part4">SOME TEXT4</div>
</div>
```

Or, this version uses the position of the clicked link to correlate with the position of the item to show:

```
$("#myLinks a").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "showall") {
        $(".all div").fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        var all = $(".all div");
        var index = $(this).index();
        var target = all.eq(index - 1);
        all.not(target).fadeOut("slow");
        target.fadeIn("slow");
    }
})
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BT2UB/

I personally like the first version because it's not position sensitive so if there are any other divs around it, they don't mess things up, but it does require settings ids and classes with trailing numbers that match.

Here's yet another version that uses data on each element to tell what it's connected to:

```
<div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#" id="showall">Show All</a>
    <a href="#" id="link1" data-sel=".part1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2" data-sel=".part2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="link3" data-sel=".part3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="link4" data-sel=".part4">Link 4</a>
</div>

<div class="all">
   <div class="part1">SOME TEXT1</div>
   <div class="part2">SOME TEXT2</div>
   <div class="part3">SOME TEXT3</div>
   <div class="part4">SOME TEXT4</div>
</div>

$("#myLinks a").click(function() {
    if (this.id == "showall") {
        $(".all div").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        var target = $(this).data("sel");
        $(".all div:visible").not(target).slideUp("slow");
        $(target).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response jfriend00.

Comment: Added another version that uses attribute data to establish which link it linked to which content.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to go with jfriend00's second method with slight modifications. You don't have to name your class `part1, part2, part3, ...`. Instead, just name them all as 'part'. Cache the selectors for performance.

```
<div id="myLinks">
    <a href="#" id="showall">Show All</a>
    <a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="link3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="link4">Link 4</a>
</div>

<div id="all">
   <div class="part">SOME TEXT1</div>
   <div class="part">SOME TEXT2</div>
   <div class="part">SOME TEXT3</div>
   <div class="part">SOME TEXT4</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $parts = $('#all .part'),
    $links = $('#myLinks a');

$links.click(function() {

    if (this.id == "showall") {

        $parts.fadeIn("slow");

    } else {

        var index = $links.index(this),
            $target = $parts.eq(index - 1);

        // If part div is not already visible
        if(!$target.is(':visible')) {

            $parts.fadeOut('slow');
            $target.fadeIn('slow');

        }

    }

});
```

Even though this method is position sensitive, it is more cleaner and you don't have to have too many ids and classes.